# How to use Gecko driver to launch Mozill browsere

Tags: selenium

I am start learning Selenium (Day 5) and using Gecko driver to launch Mozilla and getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\dev\geckodriver.exe
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:121)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:116)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$000(GeckoDriverService.java:37)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:95)
```

I copied code(Retype in eclipse):

```
package mypackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class myClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\dev\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


        driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
        driver.quit();

            }
        }
```

My Geckodriver path is C:\dev\Geckodriver
I saw same question was asked multiple time, but didn't see the above message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download `geckodriver.exe` from [this](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) link, you can not run firefox 49.0 without gecko driver. After download unzip it and store in any location on you machine then follow this code. Use Selenium version 3.0.1 for this.
If you are using older version of selenium then you have to use

```
WebDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver();
```

in place of

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Download gecko driver from this link: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\dev\\geckodriver.exe"); // you have to select you path of gecko driver where you placed it after download and unzip.
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
```

Comment: Thanks Kinjal, I have download geckodriver from same link (https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and unzip in my directory c:\dev. I also put same path in my system.setproperty.
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\dev\\geckodriver.exe"); 
But I am getting message "The driver executable does not exist: C:\dev\geckodriver.exe" even I can navigate and see file there.

Comment: Which version of selenium jars are you using?